# 3D plotly from pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, plotly

I would like to create a 3D surface graph with plotly library from pandas dataframe, however there is no result shown in python.
Could anyone help, please? Thank you in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df_final = pd.DataFrame(list(zip( new_storage_p_two,  new_storage_c_two,   new_storage_result, backward_storage_result, gap)),columns =['P2', 'C2', 'Cycle Time New Sequence', 'Cycle Time Backward Sequence','Cycle Time Difference'])
df_final.head()


z = df_final['Cycle Time Difference'] #.values
x = df_final['P2']
y = df_final['C2']

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=z, x=x, y=y)])
fig.update_traces(contours_z=dict(show=True, usecolormap=True, highlightcolor="limegreen", project_z=True))
fig.update_layout(title='Cycle Time Gap', autosize=False,
                  width=500, height=500,
                  margin=dict(l=65, r=50, b=65, t=90))
fig.show()
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahbLQ.png):[image: screenshot of pandas dataframe][image: screenshot of the 3D plot]

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the brackets around the data.  Try this:

```
df_final['Cycle Time Difference'] = df_final['Cycle Time Difference'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: Hello, There is an error message as follows:---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-b6cdde937a46> in <module>
----> 1 df_final['Cycle Time Difference'] = df_final['Cycle Time Difference'].apply(lambda x: x[0])

4 frames
<ipython-input-38-b6cdde937a46> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 df_final['Cycle Time Difference'] = df_final['Cycle Time Difference'].apply(lambda x: x[0])

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-b6cdde937a46> in <module>
----> 1 df_final['Cycle Time Difference'] = df_final['Cycle Time Difference'].apply(lambda x: x[0])

4 frames
<ipython-input-38-b6cdde937a46> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 df_final['Cycle Time Difference'] = df_final['Cycle Time Difference'].apply(lambda x: x[0])

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: What is the type of gap?  type(gap)

Comment: the type(gap) = numpy.ndarray